# How to calculate probability of choosing from pool with replacement and at least 2 are the same?

Tags: probability, random

From a group of 1000 numbers with replacement (1 ... 1000), 40 numbers are chosen evenly,
How can I find the probability that 2 (at least) chosen numbers are equal?

I thought the following: for the first number if I compare it with any other, the probability that they are equal is 1/1000, right? (The first number is given, so in the group there is only one equal number), so I thought that comparing 2 would be 1/1000 that they are equal and then I did the comparison between all the possible pairs of my 40 numbers, that would be 780 comparisons and if each has a 1/1000 chance of being the same numbers, the total probability would be 780/1000 = 78%.

But i know im wrong somewhere, I'm doing a simulation with Python ([code](https://pastebin.com/WN7suC3R)) and it gave me around 54.5% success.

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) where you pretend that there are exactly $1000$ days in the year, and you are computing that of $40$ people present in a room, at least two share a birthday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often easier to calculate the complement event and then do 1- that.  Here the complement event is that no two numbers are equal.

The first number is arbitrary,  so there is no chance of it being duplicated, or 1000/1000

The second number has 999/1000 chance of being different from the first number

Continuing onwards, we get $$\frac {1000P40} {1000^{40}}$$ ways of picking 4 numbers

Doing the compliment, $$1-\frac {1000P40} {1000^{40}}$$ gets us via wolframalpha to roughly $54.64\%$, which meshes well with your experimental data

Comment: What is 100P40 ?

Comment: 100 Permutation 40,  Ie 1000*999*....*(1000-40),  the ways of putting 40 objects out of 1000 in order

Comment: Thanks for responding. A more conventional notation for these "falling (or descending)" factorials is $1000^{\underline{40}}$ but in this case it would stop at $1000-39$

Comment: @JeanMarie nPr and nCr are standard notation in American calculators, at least.  https://byjus.com/jee-questions/what-is-npr-and-ncr-in-math/

Answer (score 0):

You have to account for 2 being equal and the rest (38) all being unequal, 3 being equal and the rest all (37) being unequal and so on.

The probability is:

$$p = {40 \choose 2} \frac{1}{1000}\left(\frac{999!}{(999-38)! 1000^{38}}\right)+{40 \choose 3} \left(\frac{1}{1000}\right)^2\left(\frac{999!}{(999-37)! 1000^{37}}\right)+\dots$$

Which can be written as:

$$p = \sum\limits_{i=2}^{39}{40 \choose i} \left(\frac{1}{1000}\right)^{i-1}\left(\frac{999!}{(999-40+i)!1000^{999-40+i}}\right)$$

---

EDIT: As @Alan points out in the comment, much easier to calculate the complement probability.

Comment: I showed the complement method above

Comment: For what it's worth, a computer assisted alternative approach is to use logarithms.  Generally, for each programming language, there will be canned facilities to the logarithm function.

Comment: I like the clomplexity of calculing the "non complement" probability, I got the first two terms of the sum, but I don get the 3rd component, the part of "the rest all being unequal". i understand that, ie. for i=2 that the rest 38 have to be all diferent so for that is the permutation 999!/(999-38)! but the part of the "1/1000^(999-41+i) shouldnt be 1/1000^(38)? bc we are puting there the other 38 numbers, right? and if we already counted the 38 numbers with the permutation, why is this all raised to the power of "39-i"?. if u dont mind to explain, this is fascinating.

Comment: btw, i tried it on wolframalpha and the result doesnt seem to make sense, i ran `Sum[Binomial[40, n]*(1/1000)^(n−1)*(999!/((999−40+n)!*1000^(999−41+n)))^(39−n), {n, 2, 39}]` ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B40%2C+n%5D*%281%2F1000%29%5E%28n%E2%88%921%29*%28999%21%2F%28%28999%E2%88%9240%2Bn%29%21*1000%5E%28999%E2%88%9241%2Bn%29%29%29%5E%2839%E2%88%92n%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+2%2C+39%7D%5D)), did i something wrong?

Comment: You're right, that was a bug. Just cleaned up the formula. Can you try now?

Comment: sry, Im still getting something without sense :( here the ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B40%2C+n%5D*%281%2F1000%29%5E%28n%E2%88%921%29*%28999%21%2F%28%28999%E2%88%9240%2Bn%29%21*1000%5E%28999%E2%88%9240%2Bn%29%29%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+2%2C+39%7D%5D)),i tried a simplest exercise constructing the sum with a dice of 6 faces (a pool of 6 instead 1000), trying to get at least 2 equal with 2,3,4 and 5 tries (instad of the 40) but with not luck. also tried to change some values inside the sum but dont know how to get it

Comment: I found out this https://datamettle.com/the-birthday-problem/ , where is described an "s(λ)" that "accounts for the 'double counting' of the multinomial coefficients", that looks hard to get, I dint got how to get it